# MSSQL, PHP and Date/DateTime

Tags: php, sql-server, datetime

I have a sqlsrv_query that fetches a date object from mssql and automatically converts it to a php datetime object that looks like this:

```
DateTime Object ( [date] => 1900-01-01 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => America/New_York )
```

If I try to pull the date string out I get:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DateTime as array
```

I have seen most people use the format property of datetime but for some reason I can't:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object
```

Any ideas on how to get the date string formatted as Y-m-d out of this query?

Comment: Can you show us how you're trying to use the object? ([Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23523511/edit) your question to include the relevant code.)

Comment: $row[0] is the datetime object I did print_r on in the first line of code. I have tried $row[0]->format('Y-m-d') and $row[0]->date.

Comment: cant reproduce it works http://codepad.viper-7.com/C3Up7a

Comment: tad bit late, but you are probably doing ```$date['date']->format('Y-m-d')``` instead of ```$date->format('Y-m-d')```, hope it helps anyone.